# Magento 2 Where is the markup of account navigation template?

Tags: magento, themes, magento2

I'm working in a bootstrap template in magento and my menu contains an ul markup for the user menu navigation, i want change the markup for this sections to a div container but i can't find the template file.

In my layout file default.xml i have

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links">
<arguments>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
</arguments>
```

But i can't find where is the markup in my template folder "Freego"

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you trace the parent classes of the navigation block you'll see it extends

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links
```

This block creates the ul element programmatically, there is no template to edit. Look at the method

```
_toHtml()
```

You can easily override the block to change the markup returned, or just wrap it in a container in the xml layout to add a div wrapper etc, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is navigated in function _toHtml()